# What is the difference between EmbeddedDocumentField and ReferenceField in mongoengine

Tags: json, dictionary, schema, mongoengine, bson

Internally, what are the differences between these two fields? What kind of schema do these fields map to in mongo? Also, how should documents with relations be added to these fields? For example, if I use

```
from mongoengine import *

class User(Document):
    name = StringField()

class Comment(EmbeddedDocument):
    text = StringField()
    tag  = StringField()

class Post(Document):
    title    = StringField()
    author   = ReferenceField(User)
    comments = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField(Comment))
```

and call

```
>>> some_author = User.objects.get(name="ExampleUserName")
>>> post = Post.objects.get(author=some_author)
>>> post.comments
[]
>>> comment = Comment(text="cool post", tag="django")
>>> comment.save()
>>>
```

should I use post.comments.append(comment) or post.comments += comment for appending this document? My original question stems from this confusion as to how I should handle this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`EmbeddedDocumentField` is just path of parent document like `DictField` and stored in one record with parent document in mongo.

To save `EmbeddedDocument` just save parent document.

```
>>> some_author = User.objects.get(name="ExampleUserName")
>>> post = Post.objects.get(author=some_author)
>>> post.comments
[]
>>> comment = Comment(text="cool post", tag="django")
>>> post.comment.append(comment)
>>> post.save()

>>> post.comment
[<Comment object __unicode__>]

>>> Post.objects.get(author=some_author).comment
[<Comment object __unicode__>]
```

See documentation: http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/defining-documents.html#embedded-documents.

Comment: I was wondering if you could offer a bit more insight in the difference between these two field types, and what usage cases do you recommend for each. I don't want to duplicate the question, so I was hopping you can add more info to yours.

Comment: `ReferenceField` is reference to another document, `EmbeddedDocumentField` is part of one document. So ManyToMany and ManyToOne relations more applied to different documents, OneToOne relation more applied to one document.

Comment: So for M:M and M:1 you'd use `EmbeddedDocumentField` and for 1:1 you'd use `ReferenceField`. Did I got that right?

Comment: No, usage should be completely depended from your requirements. For `M:M` probably better use list of references, for example `User` friendship to another `Users`. For `M:1` reference, for example `User` and his `Posts`, or list of embedded, for example, `Post` and `Post Tags`. For `1:1` reference, for example `User` and `User Activity Page`, or embedded, for example,  `User` and `User Address`. However this examples can be not good in some special cases, so I told again it depends, if you not see what better yourself, just use one of this and refactor in future when decide that chose wrong.

Comment: Sweet! Great explanation Master Obi-Wan Tbicr

Comment: I provided a little extra detail in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34952982/3271558

Answer (score 0):

This one just a sample case  where we can use embedded docs.

Lets say for example you are going to create an app that takes in requirements as they come in and save them in the db.
Now your requirement is to assign this requirement to a bunch of people each at a later stage after some processing of the requirement.

you also need to track the changes and log the activity pertaining to the processing taken place with regards to the requirement.

I know i know you might say we can use rdbms kind of relationship with refference field. but it involves in taking care of deleting obselete records in either collections which is nothing but extra code to handle the maintenance of the child collection in case of parent doc being deleted.( There are other extra efforts too that come into place ..)

instead embedded  documents are stored as part of the parent doc. which Maintaining parent will involve embedded docs too.

and it will be easy to create complex json structured data using embedded docs rather than using user logic to manipulate and process the data into a complex structure.

Now Here the relation is one requirement to many handlers(which is nothing but an activity log by the handlers for the one requirement).