# EmbeddedDocumentField and ReferenceField in mongoengine

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

I have some pretty simple code:

```
class User(db.Document):
   username = db.StringField(max_length=25)
   userid = db.StringField(max_length=25)
   password = db.StringField(max_length=25)

   def __repr__(self):
    return '<User %r>' % (self.username)


class DeviceDetails(db.Document):
    profile = ReferenceField(User)
    enduser = db.StringField(max_length=30, required = True)
    model = db.StringField(max_length=25,required = True)
    conversation = db.ListField(db.EmbeddedDocumentField('Conversation'))

   def __repr__(self):
       return self.enduser

class Conversation(db.EmbeddedDocument):
    message = db.StringField(max_length=250)
```

where every user will have some device details and some conversation linked to every device detail. The conversation is being appended to every DeviceDetails as mentioned here:  [What is the difference between EmbeddedDocumentField and ReferenceField in mongoengine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17454246/what-is-the-difference-between-embeddeddocumentfield-and-referencefield-in-mongo)
which is working fine.

Now I wish to associated a user to DeviceDetails. I tried adding the code mentioned in the "link" above. but got a error:

```
>>> from feed.models import *
>>> d = DeviceDetails(
... profile = 'aryan',
... enduser = 'two',
... model = 'nokia'
... )
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 8, in <module>
File "/home/anurag/virtual/vir/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongoengine                
/base/document.py", line 85, in __init__
value = field.to_python(value)
File "/home/anurag/virtual/vir/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongoengine/fields.py",   
line 937, in to_python
value = DBRef(collection, self.document_type.id.to_python(value))
File "/home/anurag/virtual/vir/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongoengine
/base/fields.py", line 392, in to_python
value = ObjectId(value)
File "/home/anurag/virtual/vir/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bson/objectid.py", line 90,
in __init__
self.__validate(oid)
File "/home/anurag/virtual/vir/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bson/objectid.py", line 
194, in __validate
raise InvalidId("%s is not a valid ObjectId" % oid)

InvalidId: aryan is not a valid ObjectId
```

I have some users in User model:

```
>>> User.objects.all()
[<User u'anurag'>, <User u'aryan'>]
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your schema `Profile` is a reference field, which means it will store the id of the object it references.

You should set it to be the `id` of the User aryan (or just set it to be the aryan user object) eg:

```
aryan = User.objects(name="aryan").first()
device = DeviceDetails(profile=aryan, enduser='two', model='nokia').save()
```