# What is the best choice of field for this project, using MongoEngine?

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine, flask-mongoengine

im currently working on a project and was wondering if i could get a little bit of advice. I aim to be storing information about a number of URLs, which will each have a number of parameters and will look something like this:

```
{
  Name: "Report1",
  Host: "127.0.0.1",
  Description: "This is a test report",
  Date: "00/00/00",
  Time: "00:00:00",
  Pages:{
        Page: "test_page_url",
        Parameters:{
                 Parameter: "test_param",
                 Value: "test_parm_value"
                    }

        }
```

}

I've not been able to find much information/ examples of using a one-to-many, within a one-to-many relationship using MongoEngine and was wondering what the best approach would be? Is it possible to use *EmbeddedDocumentListField* in this manner or would it be best practice to use *ReferenceField*. Any advice would be greatly appreciated as im still quite new to the NoSQL approach

Comment: This answer may help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34952982/3271558

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a simple rule, embedded documents are well suited if

- a `Parameter` belongs to only one `Page` and a `Page` and its `Parameter`s belongs to only one test
- your document won't grow over 16 Mo.

AFAIU, this is the case here, so I don't see any reason to use `ReferenceField`s, which would introduce complexity and performance penalty.

To put it simply, if you can represent your data as you did in your question, laid out as a single document rather than linking several documents together like in a relational model, then its probably safe to use embedded documents.

More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34952982/4653485) as suggested in a comment.