# What's the better mongodb document structure?

Tags: django, mongodb, mongoengine

I'm trying to create a good document structure that is having good reading performances and not so slow writing performances.
I need to store informations about a UserConnection document, that represents the link between two users in my database. Each link is having a weight that depends on a list of parameters.

The following is a schema that represents the data, the links, and weights components:

```
UserConnection      Services          Components
  UserA             Name              Name
  UserB             Weight            Weight
  Weight            Components
  Services

UserConnection.Weight = sum(UserConnection.Services.Weight)
UserConnection.Services.Weight = sum(UserConnection.Services.Weight.Components)
```

I'm currently using Mongoengine into Django. I tried to define some structure using EmbeddedDocument and EmbeddedDocumentListField, but I'm not happy about it.

I'm not adding my tests for brevity sake.

Can anyone please help me to find a good structure for MongDB?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Because mongoengine defines document structure in python classes you can use normal python class `@property` decorated methods to return calculated values.

Consider the following example:

```
import mongoengine as mdb

mdb.connect("so-37396173")


class User(mdb.Document):
    name = mdb.StringField()


class UserConnection(mdb.Document):
    user_a = mdb.ReferenceField('User')
    user_b = mdb.ReferenceField('User')
    services = mdb.ListField(mdb.ReferenceField('Service'))

    @property
    def weight(self):
        return sum([s.weight for s in self.services])


class Component(mdb.EmbeddedDocument):
    name = mdb.StringField()
    weight = mdb.FloatField()


class Service(mdb.Document):
    name = mdb.StringField()
    components = mdb.EmbeddedDocumentListField('Component')

    @property
    def weight(self):
        return sum([c.weight for c in self.components])
```

When you have a `UserConnection` object you can then access a `weight` attribute:

```
>>> uc = UserConnection.objects.first()
>>> uc.weight
0.8544546532
```

The drawback of this is that `weight` is never stored on the database in the context of a `UserConnection` so you can't aggregate it or sort on it at that level but the [aggregation framework](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/) may provide some good options. If you need to have the weight saved then you could define some [signals](http://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.io/guide/signals.html) to include it before the document is saved:

```
import mongoengine as mdb

mdb.connect("so-37396173")

class User(mdb.Document):
    name = mdb.StringField()


class UserConnection(mdb.Document):
    user_a = mdb.ReferenceField('User')
    user_b = mdb.ReferenceField('User')
    services = mdb.ListField(mdb.ReferenceField('Service'))
    weight = mdb.FloatField()


    @classmethod
    def calc_weight(cls, sender, document, **kwargs):
        document.weight =  sum([s.weight for s in document.services])

mdb.signals.pre_save.connect(UserConnection.calc_weight, sender=UserConnection)

class Component(mdb.EmbeddedDocument):
    name = mdb.StringField()
    weight = mdb.FloatField()


class Service(mdb.Document):
    name = mdb.StringField()
    components = mdb.EmbeddedDocumentListField('Component')
    weight = mdb.FloatField()

    @classmethod
    def calc_weight(cls, sender, document, **kwargs):
        document.weight =  sum([s.weight for s in document.components])

mdb.signals.pre_save.connect(Service.calc_weight, sender=Service)
```

A drawback with this is that you have to call the `save` method which means doing `update` with an `upsert=True` won't create the weights.

Whether you use embedded vs. reference depends on [what else you want to do with the data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34952982/3271558).

Comment: Thank you Steve for your answer. I have other question about it:
1. why you used ReferenceField and not EmbeddedDocument for Service collection?
2. I need to store the sum and not calculate it on the fly every time I access to the data. May be the field weight into Service can be filled using a pre_save signal to do the sum only when a component is added/modified/removed. What do you think about it?

Comment: Because EmbeddedDocuments are not stored in their own collection but are stored in the parent document collection. Having documents in a collection can make some querying and indexing a bit easier if there are many items. I agree about the signals as the right choice, I'll edit the answer to show that approach as well.

Comment: Thank you again Steve! It would be nice to have a signal that can be used in update with upsert too.